# Electromagnetic Diffusion Equation

Tags: maxwell-equations, diffusion

I am looking at a derivation for the electromagtic diffusion equation. It starts with Maxwells equations for the magneto-quasi-static case ($\frac{\partial \vec{D}}{\partial t} = 0$).
$$
\begin{align}
   \nabla \times \vec{H} &= \vec{J} \tag{1} \\
   \nabla \times \vec{E} &= -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \tag{2} \\
   \nabla \cdot \vec{B} &= 0 \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \vec{B} = \nabla \times \vec{A} \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Where $\vec{A}$ is the magnetic vector potential.Combinig (1) and (3) i get
$$
\begin{equation}
   \nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(\nabla \times \vec{A}\right) = -\nabla \times \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\begin{equation}
   \nabla \times \left(\vec{E}+\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}\right) = 0 \tag{5}
\end{equation}
$$
Now to fulfill this either $\left(\vec{E}+\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}\right)=0$, or $\exists$   a scalar potential $\varphi$ such that $\nabla \varphi = \vec{E} + \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$. The derivation I have at hand proceeds to simply state the the second option does not make physical sense and therefore we can set $\left(\vec{E}+\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}\right)=0$.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Why it does not make sense? In my opinion it makes a lot of sense, as $\varphi$ represents the scalar potential associated to the electric field. Maybe they implicitly assume to work in a specific gauge with $\varphi=0$, this can always be done due to the gauge freedom of the E.M. field

Comment: hm yeah could be. I really didn't get the whol gauging stuff though, mioght have to look into that.